# Footer not staying to bottom of Rails app when yielding in

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to get my footer to stay at the bottom of my rails app, but it's just attached to the most recent content block as seen below:

[footer not staying on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVCPh.png)

html for admin panel page:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/heading", locals: {title: 'Admin Panel', tagline: 'Accept or reject applications'} %>

<div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
  <div class="mt-8 flow-root">
    <div class="-mx-4 -my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
      <div class="inline-block min-w-full py-2 align-middle sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-0">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Role</th>
            <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Email</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Website</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Role</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Newsletter</th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Decision</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
            
            <% @user_submissions.each do |user_submission| %>
              <tr>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap py-5 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm sm:pl-0">
                  <div class="flex items-center">
                    <!-- <div class="h-11 w-11 flex-shrink-0">
                      to be done with gravatar later on
                      <img class="h-11 w-11 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517841905240-472988babdf9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
                    </div> -->
                    <div class="ml-4">
                      <div class="font-medium text-gray-900"> <%= user_submission.name %> </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-5 text-sm text-gray-500">
                  <div class="text-gray-900"> <%= user_submission.plan_name %> </div>
                </td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-5 text-sm text-gray-500">
                  <div class="text-gray-900"> <%= user_submission.email %> </div>
                </td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-5 text-sm text-gray-500"><%= user_submission.website %> </td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-5 text-sm text-gray-500"> <%= user_submission.job_role %> </td>
                <td class="px-3 py-5 text-sm text-gray-500 max-w-sm">
                  <div class="text-gray-900"> <%= user_submission.text %> </div>
                  <!-- <div class="mt-1 text-gray-500">MULTILINE</div> -->
                </td>
                <td class="flex relative whitespace-nowrap py-5 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-0">
                  <div>
                    <%= form_for user_submission, url: admin_user_submission_path(user_submission), html: { class: 'flex items-center w-full gap-2' } do |f| %>
                      <select id="user_submission_status" name="user_submission[status]" class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
                        <option selected>Pending</option>
                        <option>Approve</option>
                        <option>Reject</option>
                      </select> 
                        <!-- <%= f.submit 'Update', class: 'text-white bg-primary hover:bg-primary-hover focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center me-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800' %> -->
                      <%= button_tag( :class => "text-white bg-primary hover:bg-primary-hover focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center me-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800") do %>
                        <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
                          <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9"/>
                        </svg> 
                      <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>

            <!-- More people... -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

code for application.html.erb layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= metamagic site: ENV['COMPANY_NAME'], title: [:site, :title], separator: " | " %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="container mx-auto mt-14 px-6">
      <%= render "shared/flash" %>
      <%= render "shared/header" %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render "shared/footer" %>
    </main>

    <%= render "shared/script_tags" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

any help appreciated!

Tried doing a min-h-screen but that just mean there'd be extra to scroll down whereas I want it to fit the screen.